# CallKit Audio Initialisation Error in Background - Audio not working after first Call

Tags: ios, swift, audio, pjsip, callkit

I have added pjsip `VoIP` functionality to my iOS App recently. Using pjsip offers no problem while the App is active, I can both receive and make Calls without issues.

But I seem to have a Problem with the sound devices in the background. The first call I receive from the background works fine, I get sound and I can close it normally.

The problem is after the first call I get no sound what so ever when I accept a call from the Background. The same happens if I make or receive a call while the App is active and then go to the background and receive a call. 
When I close the app, the first Call from the background works normally again.

I have no idea what could cause that.

I have tried to manually close all calls via `CallManager` and I call a `CXEndCallAction` when the Server Side terminates the call, to get `CallKit` to close properly.

I'd be happy to post specific code passages, but currently, I have no clue where the problem could lie...

---

UPDATE:

I have figured out that the pjsip coreaudio initializes differently the second time.

Now the Question is, how do I reset CoreAudio in pjsip properly?

Successful Call Init:

```
11:03:01.615 tsx0x1030710a8  .....State changed from Trying to 
Proceeding, event=TX_MSG
11:03:01.615 dlg0x1030840a8  ......Transaction tsx0x1030710a8 state changed to Proceeding
2019-02-13 11:03:01.615745+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820452] Incoming call from "Matthias" <sip:238@80.80.245.33>
11:03:01.618    pjsua_aud.c  ..Set sound device: capture=0, playback=0
11:03:01.618    pjsua_aud.c !Set sound device: capture=0, playback=0
11:03:01.619    pjsua_aud.c !...Opening sound device PCM@16000/1/20ms
11:03:01.619 coreaudio_dev.  ....Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
2019-02-13 11:03:01.808024+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820452] [aurioc] 1029: failed: '!int' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16>)
11:03:01.851    pjsua_aud.c  ...Opening sound device PCM@44100/1/20ms
11:03:01.851 coreaudio_dev.  ....Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
2019-02-13 11:03:01.859854+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820452] [aurioc] 1029: failed: '!int' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16>)
11:03:01.860    pjsua_aud.c  ...Opening sound device PCM@48000/1/20ms
11:03:01.860 coreaudio_dev.  ....Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
2019-02-13 11:03:01.867061+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820452] [aurioc] 1029: failed: '!int' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  48000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  48000 Hz, Int16>)
11:03:01.867    pjsua_aud.c  ...Opening sound device PCM@32000/1/20ms
11:03:01.867 coreaudio_dev.  ....Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
2019-02-13 11:03:01.874321+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820452] [aurioc] 1029: failed: '!int' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  32000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  32000 Hz, Int16>)
11:03:01.875    pjsua_aud.c  ...Opening sound device PCM@16000/1/20ms
11:03:01.875 coreaudio_dev.  ....Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
2019-02-13 11:03:01.881126+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820452] [aurioc] 1029: failed: '!int' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16>)
11:03:01.881    pjsua_aud.c  ...Opening sound device PCM@8000/1/20ms
11:03:01.881 coreaudio_dev.  ....Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
2019-02-13 11:03:01.888214+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820452] [aurioc] 1029: failed: '!int' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,   8000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,   8000 Hz, Int16>)
11:03:01.888    pjsua_aud.c  ...Unable to open sound device: Unknown error -560117684 [status=-560117684]
Error in Setting of Audio Devices - IncomingCall
TESTPRINT FOR NOTIFICATION INFO: eingehender anruf von 238
TESTPRINT FOR NOTIFICATION INFO: 238
```

Unsuccessful Call Init:

```
    11:03:49.840 tsx0x103064ea8  .....State changed from Trying to Proceeding, event=TX_MSG
11:03:49.840 dlg0x1030906a8  ......Transaction tsx0x103064ea8 state changed to Proceeding
2019-02-13 11:03:49.841013+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820906] Incoming call from "Matthias" <sip:238@80.80.245.33>
11:03:49.842    pjsua_aud.c  ..Set sound device: capture=0, playback=0

11:03:49.842    pjsua_aud.c  ...Opening sound device PCM@16000/1/20ms
11:03:49.842 coreaudio_dev.  ....Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
11:03:49.847    pjsua_aud.c !Set sound device: capture=0, playback=0
2019-02-13 11:03:50.276837+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820280] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)
2019-02-13 11:03:50.277597+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820280] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Receiver (type: Receiver)
2019-02-13 11:03:50.292488+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820280] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Receiver (type: Receiver)
2019-02-13 11:03:50.293379+0100 VarioCallCTI[11928:2820280] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Receiver (type: Receiver)
11:03:50.383 coreaudio_dev. !....core audio stream started
Setting of Audio Devices Successfull - IncomingCall











TESTPRINT FOR NOTIFICATION INFO: eingehender anruf von 238
TESTPRINT FOR NOTIFICATION INFO: 238
```

Comment: issue might be after the first call ends, your cleaning up the audio session. so when the next call comes audio broken. if you kill and relaunch you are setting audio session again. so it works

Comment: I suspected as much, but if I start the App in Foreground and make or receive a SIP call the Audio works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve the Problem.

Since the PJSIP Library Init caused the coreAudio to initialize before the priority bump required by iOS was fully finished, I had to open CallKit and register at the PJSIP Server inside the CallKit - ProviderDelegate

```
  func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)?) {
let update = CXCallUpdate()
update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: handle)
update.hasVideo = hasVideo
//MARK: Final Working Solution
print("Starting PJSIP after PUSH")
pjsipfunctions.init().registersip(mainUser.sipData["User"], mainUser.sipData["Password"], mainUser.sipData["Server"])

provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
  if error == nil {
    let call = Call(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
    self.callManager.add(call: call)
    userTerminatedCall = false

  }

  completion?(error as? NSError)
}
}
}
```

Comment: hi wat excatly did u reintialise??im stuck in simialr problem,pjsip core aduio is not getting connected to iphone io sytem